# Creating a cookie that saves new home page location on first session visit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to setup the following user flow:

1. User clicks on "save my textbook" link which saves a cookie and
   offers an alert that their cookie was saved
2. When that user visits the homepage a subsequent time, jQuery checks what the value of the
   cookie is (or if it exists). The value of the cookie should correspond to the respective textbook they saved.
3. If the cookie exists, they get redirected to the url corresponding to that book
4. This happens only if the user is visiting the homepage for the first
   time during that session
5. If a user browses around the site and comes back to the home page they should not be redirected. However,if the user closes the browser and reopens the website, they should be redirected

For the cookies, I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Here is the HTML:

```
<a href="http://maccy.local:5757/core-connection-1">
  <span class="thumb">
    <img width="150" height="150" src="http://maccy.local:5757/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/400x400.jpeg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="400x400">
  </span>
</a>
<a class="save-textbook-cc1" href="#">Save this as my book</a>

<a href="http://maccy.local:5757/core-connection-2">
  <span class="thumb">
    <img width="150" height="150" src="http://maccy.local:5757/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/400x400.jpeg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="400x400">
  </span>
</a>
<a class="save-textbook-cc2" href="#">Save this as my book</a>
```

Here is the jQuery that I'm using and of course it's not working:

```
$(function() {
    var COOKIE_NAME = 'textbook-cookie'; /* create cookie */
    var VISITED = 'visited' /* track where user has landed */

    $( ".save-textbook-cc1" ).click(function() {
      $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, 'cc1', { expires: 7, path: '/index.php' });
      alert("Textbook Saved as CC1!")
      $.cookie(VISITED, 'no', { expires: 7, path: '/index.php' });
    });
    $( ".save-textbook-cc2" ).click(function() {
      $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, 'cc2', { expires: 7, path: '/index.php' });
      alert("Textbook Saved as CC2!")
      $.cookie(VISITED, 'no', { expires: 7, path: '/index.php' });
    });

    $go = $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME);
    $visited = $.cookie(VISITED);
    if ($go == 'cc1' ) AND ($visited == 'no') {
        window.location = "/core-connection-1";
        $.cookie(VISITED, 'yes', { expires: 7, path: '/index.php' });
    }
    elseif ($go == 'cc2' ) AND ($visited == 'no') {
        window.location = "/core-connection-2";
        $.cookie(VISITED, 'yes', { expires: 7, path: '/index.php' }); {
    }
    else {
    }
});
```

Comment: "_of course it's not working_" - please define what is not working.

Comment: By "not working," I mean that nothing is happening. Not even being redirecting when going to the home page. I'm guessing the code logic is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you do this with PHP?

1. Set a cookie
2. Check for the cookie & referrer
3. If referrer is not from the same domain and cookie has been set, redirect to the corresponding page. If referrer is from the same domain, just show the homepage :)

Check out PHP.net for how to set cookies with PHP:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php
or on W3Schools
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

P.S. If you really want to do this with javascript, please elaborate the "it's not working"-bit please :)

Comment: I don't mind doing this with PHP, but I assume some jQuery is needed because a textbook is saved by clicking a link/button. Doesn't that mean there needs to be a click event? By "not working," I mean that nothing is happening. Not even being redirecting when going to the home page. I'm guessing the code logic is wrong.